# How to handle URL-encoded POST request with self-hosted WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have self-hosted WCF service. It works as charm, when the input data format is known, but it's not my case.

My service would be invoked like a HTML form would be posted to it, but I don't know exact list of parameters which would be sent.

External web service would send a HTTP request with content `"a=foo&b=bar"`, yes, URL-encoded. Parameters in content may vary. Their count may vary. Some parameters may or may not be present. So I'm perfectly fine with whole URL-encoded string, I'll decode it myself. I have to reply with ASCII string "OK".

How to access this `"a=foo&b=bar"` text from the request? Can I create my own encoder? How it's done?

Here's what I started with, the contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "test", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Stream TestPostRequest();
```

And here's the method:

```
public Stream TestPostRequest() {
    var maxByteSize = 16384;
    var messageStream = new MemoryStream(maxByteSize);
    var messageBuffer = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(maxByteSize);
    messageBuffer.WriteMessage(messageStream);
    var rawRequestData = new byte[maxByteSize];
    messageStream.Read(rawRequestData, 0, maxByteSize);
    var requestDataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawRequestData);
    Console.WriteLine(requestDataString);
    var responseData = new byte[2] { 79, 75 }; // OK
    var responseStream = new MemoryStream(responseData);
    return responseStream;
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work, because `CreateBufferedCopy` method expects XML as input data, but gets URL-encoded string. As all the other methods I found.

I'm not afraid of creating new class implementing `IEndpointBehavior` or `IDispatchMessageInspector`, but I just don't see where I could implement something allowing me to access the request data raw, as bytes, not XML.

Maybe there is a point where I could convert raw data to XML?

**EDIT:**

My fault, there was a broken behavior in my operation stack which messed with message content type badly. The moral is - test new features isolated, in a clean test project. The second moral is WCF can everything ;) And the third is: if there is no XML in message internal data - you broke it ;)